# Effect of concentration on rate

Tags: kinetics

[image]

How do I solve this question?

My thinking is this: since O2 is not a reactant in any step, and since the reaction rate depends only on the reactants, increasing the concentration of O2 does not affect the rate of the reaction.

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Hint: What defines a reactant ?

Comment: A reactant is a species that undergoes effective collisions to give product species. But O2 does not undergo collision to form product species. So it is not a reactant.. right?

Comment: Hint No 2: What do the bidirectional arrows mean ?

Comment: That it is a reversible reaction. So increasing concentration of O2 would increase concentration of O3. O3 is a reactant in the rate determining step. So the rate of reaction increases??

Comment: Hint No 3 (last): Enumerate equations of reaction rates, determine conditions for steady state of one of the intermittent species and express decomposition rate as function of O2 concentration. Be aware the site is not a free online service for solving homework or alike tasks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by determining the conditions for steady state? I'm not sure I know how to do that. I don't want just the answer, I want to know how to solve these kinds of problems. I would appreciate if you have any links related to this problem which I can read, and understand how to solve these type of problems. Thanks for replying.

Comment: steady state for [X] means d[X]/dt=0, rate of production X equals the rate of its consumption.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105998/discussion-between-poutnik-and-michael-faraday).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question is solved. Poutnik taught me to do it using steady state approximation :)
[image]

Just adding the image for somebody who might find this in future.